How do I add a std::unique_ptr owning a CDialogEx to a std::vector avoiding "attempting to reference a deleted function"?
C++ and Windows are fighting with each other, and I need to get them to stop.
I have a Visual Studio 2022 generated class that implements CDialogEx, and I need to add this to an array capable of insert. This is hard.
The class that Visual Studio 2022 generated for the dialog looks like this:
class SignPage : public CDialogEx
{
    DECLARE_DYNAMIC(SignPage)

public:
    SignPage(CWnd* pParent = nullptr);   // standard constructor
    virtual ~SignPage();

// Dialog Data
#ifdef AFX_DESIGN_TIME
    enum { IDD = IDD_SIGN_PAGE };
#endif

protected:
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // DDX/DDV support

    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};

The implementation of the class generated by Visual Studio looks like this:
// SignPage.cpp : implementation file
//

#include "pch.h"
#include "App.h"
#include "afxdialogex.h"
#include "SignPage.h"


// SignPage dialog

IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(SignPage, CDialogEx)

SignPage::SignPage(CWnd* pParent /*=nullptr*/)
    : CDialogEx(IDD_SIGN_PAGE, pParent)
{

}

SignPage::~SignPage()
{
}

void SignPage::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
}


BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(SignPage, CDialogEx)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


// SignPage message handlers

I understand that the array capable of insert is std::vector, however inserting any Windows generated objects into std::vector results in "attempting to reference a deleted function" errors as Windows has deleted the copy and move functions in their objects.
I do not want the array capable of insert to molest the Windows provided objects in any way, and so I understand std:unique_ptr is what I need so that I add a pointer to the Windows provided objects to the list.
I instantiate the object and vector like this, and the compiler likes it:
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<SignPage>> m_dlgs;
std::unique_ptr<SignPage> upm_dlg1 = std::make_unique<SignPage>();

Now I try and insert the upm_dlg1 into m_dlgs like this:
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<SignPage>>::iterator it;
it = m_dlgs.begin();
m_dlgs.insert(it, upm_dlg1); <---- error happens here

The addition of the last line above causes a compile error inside the template rendering unique pointers as follows:
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.40.33807\include\xmemory(700,82): error C2280: 'std::unique_ptr<SignPage,std::default_delete<SignPage>>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<SignPage,std::default_delete<SignPage>> &)': attempting to reference a deleted function

Does anyone know what steps I must take to fix this?
My limitations are:

The objects I need to add to the array capable of insert are generated by Visual Studio for the benefit of Windows. My options to modify these objects are limited.

The compiler error is being triggered deep inside what I understand to be the template implementing unique_ptr. I am assuming this is the joy of c++ compiler errors.

I am led to believe that std::vector is the collection I should be using, but this may not be the case, can anyone confirm? I have no need for sorting or any other complexity, just a simple array where I can insert and remove without in any way touching the object in the list.



You can't copy std::unique_ptr, so you need to transfer ownership of the dialog to the vector using m_dlgs.insert(it, std::move(upm_dlg1));

The deleted function is the copy constructor for unique_ptr. The pointer cannot be copied, because then it wouldn't be unique anymore! So you have to move it instead.

This line:
m_dlgs.insert(it, upm_dlg1);

Attempts to create a copy of upm_dlg1 inside the std::vector.
But since it is a std::unique_ptr it cannot be copied:
The copy constructor of std::unique_ptr is deleted, which is the reason for the error "attempting to reference a deleted function".
Instead you should move the object into the std::vector by using std::move in the following way:
//----------------vvvvvvvvv------------
m_dlgs.insert(it, std::move(upm_dlg1));

A side note:
std::move does not really move anything:

std::move is used to indicate that an object t may be "moved from",
i.e. allowing the efficient transfer of resources from t to another
object.

In practice this is done via a cast to an R value reference.
However the final result is exactly what you need because it will trigger using the proper overload of std::vector::insert, performing a move instead of a copy.

@GrahamLeggett is anything missing from my answer above ? Please let me know if you need any further clarification.
